# How to modify default android app

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to develop a contacts app with some modified features. How can I import the open source default android contacts app into Android Studio so that I can add my new features?

Comment: AOSP app projects are designed to built as part of a full firmware build, not as an ordinary app merely relying upon the Android SDK. While you are welcome to use the code, the project may require substantial modification to work as a standalone SDK project, before you even begin adding in your own features.

Answer (score 1):

**Most of the handset provider customize the contacts app, to get handset specific app  you need to **extract the contacts app apk and reverse engineer it**.
**Refer the source code provided by google here(nexus devices)** https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts
**you can read and learn how to develop it here** http://www.cs.trincoll.edu/hfoss/wiki/Tutorial:Making_a_Contacts_Application

Comment: I already saw the repo that you posted, but I can't build the project in Android Studio. Any suggestions?